# Check constraint for a flag column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database is MS SQLServer

Data example:

```
| Name | defaultValue |  value   |
| one  |     true     | valone   |
| one  |     false    | valtwo   |
| one  |     false    | valthree |
```

I'm after a way of constraining the table such that each 'Name' can only have one row with 'defaultValue' set to true

Answer (score 1):

Create a computed column like this:

```
  ALTER TABLE yourtable
  ADD ValueCheck AS CASE defaultValue
     WHEN true THEN 1
     WHEN false THEN NULL
  END
```

and then add unique constraint for (Name, ValueCheck)

Comment: I +1ed this but then realised it doesn't work. Unique constraints in SQL Server only allow 1 NULL.

Comment: If yourtable has a key column (eg. keyid), then changing NULL to keyid above should work.

Comment: (and changing ...when true then 1... to ...when true then 0...)

Answer (score 1):

I liked Michael's idea but it will only allow you one false value per name in SQL Server. To avoid this how about using

```
  ALTER TABLE yourtable
  ADD [ValueCheck] AS 
     (case [defaultValue] when (1) then ('~Default#?@') /*Magic string!*/
                 else value  end) persisted
```

and then add unique constraint for (Name, ValueCheck).

I am assuming that name, value combinations will be unique. If the value column does not allow NULLs then using `NULL` rather than the magic string would be preferable otherwise choose a string that cannot appear in the data (e.g. 101 characters long if the value column only allows 100 chars)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx) to validate this constraint on update or insert events and roll back the  transaction if it was invalid.

Comment: But make sure you take into account the effects of snapshot isolation http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/tags/Isolation/default.aspx